# Using Call Symput

Tags: sas

I am new to SAS and I want to know if we can get the max of sales through Call Symput and also do any calculations like ADD or SUB in the data step to the existing sales values

```
data sales; 
input Product $1. Month1 Month2 Month3;
cards;
A   40  32  16 
B   63  63  10
C   61  67  28
D   84  13  83
E   51  44  63
;
run;
```

Comment: What would be the purpose of creating such a macro variable?  Basic assignment statements will let you do calculations in a data step.  You will need to provide more details about what you want to add or subtract.  Providing the expected resulting dataset would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: I am trying to learn more about Call Symput. so, would like to know how to use Call Symput to determine the max of all the integer variables in in the dataset and to use that max variable to add or subtract with the existing numbers in the dataset. This entire exercise if for my learning and I am unable to make headway in this regard. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It does not make much sense to use macro variables to store floating point values. You will lose precision in the transfer to/from character strings.  Perhaps you could find a better use case for passing values through macro variables?  For example to use a string to help generate a TITLE statement.

Comment: What is the max of SALES?  Your data does not have any variable by that name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do calculations there is no need for using the macro processor to generate code.  For example if you want to calculate the difference between each month's sales value and the mean for that product over all three months just use regular SAS code.

```
data want;
   set sales ;
   mean_sales = mean( of month1-month3);
   diff1 = month1 - mean_sales;
   diff2 = month2 - mean_sales;
   diff3 = month3 - mean_sales;
run;
```

If you want to reduce that repetitive code (say you had 20 variables instead of just 3) then look into using ARRAY statement in the data step.

Results:

```
                              mean_
Product Month1 Month2 Month3  sales    diff1     diff2     diff3

   A      40     32     16   29.3333  10.6667    2.6667  -13.3333
   B      63     63     10   45.3333  17.6667   17.6667  -35.3333
   C      61     67     28   52.0000   9.0000   15.0000  -24.0000
   D      84     13     83   60.0000  24.0000  -47.0000   23.0000
   E      51     44     63   52.6667  -1.6667   -8.6667   10.3333
```